# The type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: java, jwt

I'm working on a project and my problem is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. It's doesn't work. It's say "The type WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated" do you know why?
Can you help me please? I don't know what to do

Comment: See this: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 4):

## WebSecurityConfigAdapter is now deprecated you can use this one

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter become deprecated in the version 5.7.0-M2 of  Spring Security.

For more details you can read the blog posted by Spring io [here !](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).

Comment: Hello Oussama, thanks !! I'm a little bit confuse, i need to use the JWT but I don't understand what to do ^^' Where to start the changment on my project..

Comment: Simply follow a tuto and try to learn about it, i recomand for you these two tuto  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg  |||||||||||||||    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm-8qfMWEV8&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE